# Google Maps Clustering Markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, cluster-analysis

i have a list of markers but i want to change them as address.

```
var data = { 
"loc": [
{"longitude": -81.81718856098772, "latitude": 26.278657439364583 }
,
{"longitude": -81.81291211952795, "latitude": 26.199298735114475}
,
{"longitude": -81.74875180993064, "latitude": 26.17671864599891}
,
{"longitude": -81.81840385421958, "latitude": 26.413368581756345}
,
{"longitude": -81.75321715140747, "latitude": 26.34072059838751}

]}
```

Something like this, i want to know what is the data needed to call on the address in markers so that i can cluster them.

```
var data = { 
"address": [
{"address": 7970 GLENTIES Ln }
,
{"address": 8022 Caminito Mallorca}
,
{"address": 2750 Wheatstone St # 26}

]}
```

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by clustering? Do you want to learn which locations are close to each other? If so, why not use kmeans (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) directly on lat lon data? After the clustering is completed, you can reverse geocoding.

Comment: please refer to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317594/cluster-marker-google-maps-using-geocoder/8321597#8321597

Answer (score 1):

You probably need [reverse geocoding (address lookup)](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding). Also see [example here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse.html).

You can also find more info in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306836/how-to-prompt-user-for-place-using-google-maps-in-javascript).

Comment: Thanks but how can i cluster marker it? im gonna fetch the data from json so it would be like that.