# Cluster Marker Google Maps using geoCoder

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

Using this data

```
   var data = {
  'address': [
    {
      'address': '7970 GLENTIES Ln'
    },
    {
      'address': '8022 Caminito Mallorca'
    },
    {
      'address': '2750 Wheatstone St # 26'
    },
    {
      'address': '335 49th St'
    }  
  ]
};
```

i manage to marker them but i was unable to cluster them. below the code that I've use.

```
var markerArray = [];
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var address;
    var markers = [];
    for (var level in data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data[level].length; i++) {
       //   var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
          var dataAdd =  data[level][i];
        //  alert(dataAdd.address);
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': dataAdd.address}, function(results){            
          var marker  = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map, 
              position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
         markerArray[i] = marker;         
        });
        }
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerArray);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

How can i cluster them? it seem that the MarkerClusterer is not working or i dont know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the geocodeing function is async you need to create the marker clusterer before the markers have been created.

what you should do is create the MarkerClusterer before you start geocoding and then instead of adding to a marker array you can instead just add it to the MarkerClusterer.

Comment: im kinda confuse on what you want me to do. can you gimme a example for this?

Comment: Update: i manage to cluster them but the problem occur again google map limit the use of goecode "over query limit". hope help me with this one

Comment: You shouldn't geocode the same data everytime a user loads the page. If your data doesn't change often then geocode it once and store it for sometime. This is acceptable with the terms of service, you just can't keep it for ever.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, geocoding function is async. so, You can add marker in cluster later on using addMarker() method.

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerArray);
for (var level in data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data[level].length; i++) {      
      var dataAdd =  data[level][i];
      geocoder.geocode({ 'address': dataAdd.address}, function(results){            
      var marker  = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map, 
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
     markerArray[i] = marker;  
     markerCluster..addMarker(marker);       
    });
    }
}
```